# Why does Unity 2020 give an error CS1503?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and C# code. I am doing a basic step by step tutorial from Brackeys and for no obvious reason I get this error that says "error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'". The error appears on both rb.AddForce lines. Does anyone know what's the problem here? I am using Unity 2020.3.29f1 Personal.

Thanks for your help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardForce = 2000f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("d") )
        {
            rb.AddForce(500 * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a") )
        {
            rb.AddForce(-500 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See the first rb.AddForce.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand your comment. As mentioned I see that error against both AddForce lines within the "if" blocks

Comment: AddForce needs 3 parameters. You passed 3s in the first AddForce, but you passed only 1 parameter in the last two AddForce.

Comment: Force needs direction so you either give it a direction by multiplying a Vector3, or use 3 floats overload to indicate on which axis you're adding the force. Check derHugo's answer for how to do those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different overloads of [`AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html).

```
AddForce(Vector3 [, ForceMode])
```

and

```
AddForce(float, float, float [, ForceMode])
```

where the `ForceMode` is optional for both.

You are passing in only one single parameter `float` so the compiler thinks you want to use the first overload and tries in vain to convert the given `float` into a `Vector3` and obviously doesn't find any implemented way to do such thing.

You probably rather want

```
rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * 500 * Time.deltaTime);
```

or

```
rb.AddForce(500 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
```